# Renaming Column Not Working even Though Syntax is Correct in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have been trying to rename the column name in a csv file which I have been working on through Google-Colab. But the same line of code is working on one column name and is also not working for the other.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("Daily Bike Sharing.csv",
                   index_col="dteday",
                   parse_dates=True)
dataset = data.loc[:,["cnt","holiday","workingday","weathersit",
                      "temp","atemp","hum","windspeed"]]
dataset = dataset.rename(columns={'cnt' : 'y'})
dataset = dataset.rename(columns={"dteday" : 'ds'})
dataset.head(1)
```

The Image below is the dataframe called **data**
[image]

The Image below is **dataset**
[image]

This image is the final output which I get when I try to rename the dataframe.
[image]

The column name "**dtedate**" is not getting renamed but "**cnt**" is getting replaced "**y**" by the same code. Can someone help me out, I have been racking my brain on this for sometime now.

Comment: Are you trying to rename a column named `dteday` or `dtedate`, because in your code it is `dteday` but you specify that the column name is `dtedate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're setting **dteday** as your index, upon reading in the csv, whereas **cnt** is quite simply a column. Avoid the **index_col** attribute in **read_csv** and instead perform **dataset = dataset.set_index('ds')** after renaming.

An alternative in which only your penultimate line (trying to rename the index) would need to be changed:

```
dataset.index.names = ['ds']
```

Comment: Worked like the charm. I was trying to find a way to rename the index column and that's when you suggested the code. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the 'index-col' in the read statement, include 'dtedate' in your dataset and then change the column name. You can make the column index using df.set_index later.